# Select until sum lenght is close to value of php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP variable `$total_km`, which holds the exact value for example: 360

Then in my database I have a table where I'm storing routes and how long they are.

```
     Route     ¦    Length 
-------------------------------- 
 Praha - Brno  ¦ 120
```

Is there a way to select random routes until the summed length of routes are +-10 or equal to the predefined exact value of the variable `$total_km`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT tabCesty.odkud AS odkud, tabCesty.kam AS kam, tabCesty.km AS km, SUM(tabCesty.km) AS celkem_km 
FROM tabCesty
INNER JOIN tabUsers ON tabCesty.user_id=tabUsers.ID 
AND tabCesty.user_id = $id_uzivatele
```

Comment: Do the routes need to connect somehow?

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Comment: the best way to do this is using stored procedure

Comment: No, they do not have to be connected,

Comment: The output should be randomly selected rows until the combined lenght of the rows are +-10 or equal to $total_km variable

Comment: What should happen if the next random selection puts the sum to >370 (more than +10 from your target number)? Stop there? Discard it and try again?

Comment: I think it should discard it and try again to find another route which will fit until the condition is met.

Comment: Is your routes table very large?

Comment: Can't you select more records and loop through them in php? It seems to be easier solution.

Comment: The route table will be large because it will hold all routes of all users, but the query will run only for 1 user at the time. And 1 user have cca 20-40 rows

Comment: Yes, php is also option for me, but im really a novice and i am strugling with this problem

Comment: You want discrete optimization algorithm. You may check if coursera still will have the course open some time soon. Check this lecture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IbJf4oXOxU

Comment: Why SUM(tabCesty.km) is selected? This query doesn't make much sense because of not full GROUP BY - you are using aggregate SUM() function without specifying group field and selecting fields that are not affected in grouping.